# Converting coordinates to longitude and latitude using pyproj

Tags: python, pyproj

I am trying to convert coordinates to longitude and latitude using Pyproj, however I get an error that I am unable to solve:

b'no arguments in initialization list'

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:3942')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
x1,y1 = 685833.3,6236964.799
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print(x2,y2)
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: The error message would help

Comment: b'no arguments in initialization list'

Comment: How did you install the module? What OS you have ?

Comment: Did you check my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You activate the environment and then install everything other than Python in it. But latest proj builds set PROJ_LIB and you need to activate the environment after installing it. Easiest fix was to request all needed packages when creating the environment, and then activate it.

Make sure you:

- Youare installing in an environment, not the root.
- activate after installing proj (or pyproj).
- Make sure you have Cython installed.

I've created a simple virtual environment with virtualenv for python3.7 and your script runs fine.